# Store bands in temporary file Rasterio

Tags: rasterio, in-memory

As I'm using multiple functions in one process, I would like to pass results of each function to the next one using an In-memory File. I'm using Rasterio and I saw that there is a way to create In-memory files [in the documentation](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/memory-files.html), but unfortunately it seems like it's not working like usual files. I cannot use `open(temporaryfile).meta.copy()` to get infos (GTIFF in my case) of the file.

Is there a way to correctly store everything as in a Gtiff file but in a memory file or do I have to process in another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass instances of `MemoryFile` or datasets opened from them to functions. For example:

```py
>>> def print_metadata(dataset):
...     print(dataset.profile)
...
>>> from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
>>> tif_bytes = open('/Users/seang/code/rasterio/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif', 'rb').read()
>>> with MemoryFile(tif_bytes) as memfile:
...     with memfile.open() as dataset:
...         print_metadata(dataset)
...
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint8', 'nodata': 0.0, 'width': 791, 'height': 718, 'count': 3, 'crs': CRS({'init': 'epsg:32618'}), 'transform': Affine(300.0379266750948, 0.0, 101985.0,
   0.0, -300.041782729805, 2826915.0), 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'pixel'}
```

Note well that when the idented `with` block ends, the in-memory file is deleted. This is to give you control over memory allocation on your computer. The Rasterio dataset object is also closed at this point.

```py
>>> dataset.closed
True
>>> memfile.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/seang/envs/rio-blog-post/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/env.py", line 305, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/seang/envs/rio-blog-post/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/io.py", line 112, in open
    raise IOError("I/O operation on closed file.")
OSError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

If you pass them to functions after this, they can't be operated on. Keep your memory file open in your main program and all will be fine.